# How to flip the switches on multiple items in a SectionList at the same time?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

**Problem:** I am using React Native and I have a SectionList with custom components comprised of a Text element and a Switch element. Some of the items in each Section can be duplicates and I would like for the functionality to be if I switch item "Lesson 3" from section 1 that it would change any other "Lesson 3" items to also being switched on. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have individual status of the switch and when a switch is turned on then corresponding name is searched and turned it on.

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/awkward-turkish-delight

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  SectionList,
  Switch,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import AwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
 

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isEnabled: true,
      DATA: [
  {
    title: 'Main dishes',
    data: [
      { name: 'Pizza', status: false },
      { name: 'Burger', status: false },
      { name: 'Risotto', status: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Sides',
    data: [
      { name: 'French Fries', status: false },
      { name: 'Onion Rings', status: false },
      { name: 'Risotto', status: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Drinks',
    data: [
      { name: 'Water', status: false },
      { name: 'Coke', status: false },
      { name: 'Burger', status: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Desserts',
    data: [
      { name: 'Cheese Cake', status: false },
      { name: 'Ice Cream', status: false },
      { name: 'Pizza', status: false }
    ],
  },
] 
    };
  }

  toggleSwitch(e) {
    // console.log(DATA.length);
    for(var i=0; i< this.state.DATA.length; i++){
      // console.log(DATA[i].data)
      for(var j=0; j< this.state.DATA[i].data.length; j++){ 
        // console.log(DATA[0].data[j].name) 
        // console.log(this.state.DATA[i].data[j].name)
        if(e==this.state.DATA[i].data[j].name){
          // console.log('match found')
          var tempData = this.state.DATA
          if(tempData[i].data[j].status==true){
            tempData[i].data[j].status = false
          }else{
            tempData[i].data[j].status =true
          }

          this.setState({
            DATA:tempData
          })
        }
      } 

    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SectionList
          sections={this.state.DATA}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10 }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, marginTop: 5 }}>{item.name}</Text>
              <Switch
                trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff' }}
                thumbColor={item.status ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
                ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                onValueChange={()=>{this.toggleSwitch(item.name)}}
                value={item.status}
              />
            </View>
          )}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 18,
                marginTop: 10,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                color: 'white',
                width: '50%',
              }}>
              {title}
            </Text>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```